# Encoding payloads for GWT version 7

Tags: web-application, javascript, sql-injection

I'm auditing a website built with Google Web Toolkit. It uses serialization version 7, so the tools from GDS Security won't work (they only work till version 5). Using this technique I got all classes, but I can't deobfuscate the methods:

https://code.google.com/archive/p/degwt/

I identified a couple of RPC client requests that can be used to try SQL injection. They are actually human readable, so I can identify the fields being sent and suitable to fiddle and insert payloads. Something like:

```
POST /mywebapp/auth HTTP/1.1

..

Content-Type: text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=UTF-8

..

7|0|http://192.168.1.1:8888/mywebapp/ ....D031DD0CECD85E06AF1E383A0.gwt.authservice. java.method..|variable1|1|2|3|2...
```

I want to be gentle, and use only a few specific payloads to try and get some information about the database running on the server.

My question would be, before starting trying these payloads, do I need to encode them in a specific way so that they'll be correctly parsed server side? or there isn't a way to know this and I have to just try diferent kinds of encodings?

I'm using Burpsuite intruder to do the job, but I'm open to other tools if they are capable to do what I need.